What is this movie where a man kills 2 women at the end?
I watched this Spanish movie back in the 2000s where a woman had hidden cameras everywhere in this building and here’s what I remember:

A man and woman arguing in a room and the woman suddenly stabs the man in the heart with a pair of scissors.
The woman watching them through a hidden camera comes to help the woman who was panicking after killing the man.
A scene of the women having sex with each other, I don’t know if it was before or after killing the man.
A man in a suit comes at the end telling the women that people would pay a lot of money to watch whatever they recorded.
The man kills both of them with a gun.

I also remember that one of the woman was wearing a white shirt and had long dark hair and the other was wearing a blue tank top with some sort of curvy hair.
If anyone knows about this movie please let me know. 
